# Accessing HTTPS URL With Credentials

Tags: c#

I have a HTTPS URL which i am trying to connect to but not able to and keep getting 401 unauthorized. 
I tried to access the same URL over Web Browser (both at home and in company) and was able to connect to it. After i execute the HTTPS URL (which has some parameters in it like date etc) in the browser, it prompts for username and pwd and when i enter it, it gives the xml back in response. 
I tried following segment of code on my home PC and it worked fine but when i tried same in office network, it gave me 407 error. I thereafter embedded the proxy code in it and now i don't get 407 rather i keep getting 401. Please help

Working Code on Home:

```
public static void WorkingCode()
{
    string URL = "https://webservice.XYZ.com/display/?start_date=2015-05-06&end_date=2015-05-07";
    Uri uri = new Uri(URL);
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username123", "Password123");
    string results;
    results = wc.DownloadString(uri);
    Console.Write(results);
    Console.Read();
}
```

Code within Organization with PROXY:

```
public static void WorkingCode()
{
    string URL = "https://webservice.XYZ.com/display/?start_date=2015-05-06&end_date=2015-05-07";
    Uri uri = new Uri(URL);
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username123", "Password123");
    string results;

    /* PROXY CODE*/
    WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("frproxyseczom.PPP.com", 8080);
    myProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    wc.Proxy = myProxy;

    /*---------------*/
    results = wc.DownloadString(uri);

    Console.Write(results);
    Console.Read();
}
```

Because of security reasons, i have modified some details such as URL's, username and pwd.

Comment: "keep getting 401 unauthorized." -- is ambiguous. What are the full contents of the `WWW-Authenticate` header(s) on the response? (Use Fiddler if you're not sure).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a 401 in the proxy code because you're missing "http://" in the web proxy address.